# Why Greatest Lower Bound of this lattice does not exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, relations, lattice-orders

[f^g does not exist in this lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz4Ou.jpg)

Well in this problem greatest lower bound of f^g (i.e. f meets g) does not exist.
Why is it so. Since we could have b or e as GLB.

Any help/answers will be appreciated

Comment: if it exists then GLB is unique, here you cannot compare $b$ and $e$.

Comment: $b$ and $e$ are maximal common lower bounds, but they are not comparable.

Comment: I think it is because both $e$ and $b$ are lower bounds (for both $f$ and $g$), but $e$ and $b$ are not comparable, so it doesn't make sense to say one is greater than the other. But both are greater than the other two common lower bounds (between $f$ and $g$), namely $a$ and $c$.

Comment: But why cant we have e as Greatest lower bound ?

Answer (score 0):

A greatest lowest bound has the property that it is greater then all other lower bounds.  b is not grater then e so it can't be the greatest lower bound (likewise for e).

Comment: But why cant we have e as Greatest lower bound ?

Comment: Because e is not greater then b.